# Using Npyscreen not for the whole terminal

Tags: python, forms, user-interface

I am currently using Npyscreen to create an interface, however I am really struggling to find out how to make it not take the full screen. I would like it to create the wrapper and main form with automated width, but height of 20 rows.

```
class App(npyscreen.NPSAppManaged):
def onStart(self):
    self.registerForm("MAIN", MainForm())

class MainForm(npyscreen.Form):
def create(self):
    self.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name = "Text:", value= "Hello" )

def afterEditing(self):
    self.parentApp.setNextForm(None)
```

This is the absolutely basic one, however I cannot seem to interpret the instructions on the following page properly:

http://npyscreen.readthedocs.org/form-objects.html

Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this line:

```
self.registerForm("MAIN", MainForm())
```

this:

```
self.addForm("MAIN", MainForm(), lines=20)
```